# rowUpdating seems to fire off twice - erroring out with too many arguments the second time

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that I am attempting to update the row. If I put a breakpoint on the row updating event it gets hit the first time through and the row is updated successfully. As I continue to step through that code is not hit a second time, however I get an exception that the stored procedure from that update has too many parameters and throws an error.

I do have the autoeventwireup set to true. Is this a problem? I tried setting it to false but I have other things going on in the page_load that doesn't happen and breaks the page. Plus, from what I've read it might not be the issue. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the stack trace on the error

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Procedure or function RecordingUpdateName has too many arguments specified.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +2084358
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5096328
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2294
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +215
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +987
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) +178
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +137
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteDbCommand(DbCommand command, DataSourceOperation operation) +394
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteUpdate(IDictionary keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues) +697
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Update(IDictionary keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback) +95
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleUpdate(GridViewRow row, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean causesValidation) +1226
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +855
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +121
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +125
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +169
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +9
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +176
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

And:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdvwRecordings" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="sqldataRecordings"
    EmptyDataText="No recordings have been saved. Select Call Now below. "
    DataKeyNames="RecordingID"
    onrowdeleting="grdvwRecordings_RowDeleting"
    onrowupdating="grdvwRecordings_RowUpdating"
    onrowediting="grdvwRecordings_RowEditing"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    onrowdatabound="grdvwRecordings_RowDataBound">

    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Recording">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblRecordingName" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtRecordingName" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Recorded">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblDateRecorded" Text='<%# Bind("EntryDate") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Duration">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblDuration" Text='<%# Bind("Duration") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqldataRecordings" SelectCommand="[RecordingSelectByClient]"
   SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" runat="server"
   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VB %>"
   onselecting="AddClientIDParameter_Selecting"
   UpdateCommand="RecordingUpdateName"
   UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"
   DeleteCommand="RecordingDelete"
   DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure">

    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="RecordingName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="RecordingID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And:

```
protected void grdvwRecordings_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

   this.sqldataRecordings.UpdateParameters["RecordingID"].DefaultValue = e.Keys["RecordingID"].ToString();
   this.sqldataRecordings.UpdateParameters["RecordingName"].DefaultValue = e.NewValues["Name"].ToString();

    this.sqldataRecordings.Update();
}
```

Comment: What is the call signature of the update stored procedure?

Comment: [dbo].[RecordingUpdateName] @RecordingID int,@RecordingName varchar(100)

Comment: The procedure works fine the first time through. I just don't know why it gets called again and fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following:

Remove `onrowupdating="grdvwRecordings_RowUpdating"` from the GridView attributes

In the `SqlDataSource` tag replace the `UpdateParameters` with:

```
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="RecordingName" QueryStringField="Name" Type="String" />
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="RecordingID" QueryStringField="RecordingID" Type="String" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

I think what is happening is you are specifying your update command once in the GridView (using the `OnRowUpdated` attribute) and once in the `SqlDataSource`.

**Edit:**
As Tim Brooks indicated in the comments below, he needed to use `<%# Eval("Name") %>` instead of Bind, as the bound fields were automatically being added as parameters to the update command.

Also, I would not worry about exposing your primary key by making my suggested changes.  Since this is a web app and you are getting the RecordingID from the GridViewUpdateEventArgs you are already passing the information down to the user's computer in the ViewState.  If this is not acceptable I suggest you encrypt the ViewState.  There may be a noticeable performance hit, but the ViewState will be safe from reading.
See [Page.ViewStateEncryptionMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.viewstateencryptionmode.aspx), [Encrypt ViewState in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479501.aspx), and [Securing View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178199.aspx) for more information.

If you need a primer on ViewState You might start with [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx), but I am sure there are many other good ones out there.

Comment: Same error, however by removing the onrowupdating the change never hits the database. If this technique would have worked would I be exposing my primary key in a querystring, correct? I was setting the parameter in the code behind to avoid that.

Comment: I'm adding a parameter in the sql datasource when I select - onselecting="AddClientIDParameter_Selecting". Could that be getting called somehow? Since the onrowupdating works, I'd love to figure out how to keep that and remove whatever is calling this a second time. thank you for the help

Comment: I tried moving the information to the code behind and removed the update parameter and command from the aspx, but it behaves the same way. `this.sqldataRecordings.UpdateCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
        this.sqldataRecordings.UpdateCommand = "RecordingUpdateName";
        this.sqldataRecordings.UpdateParameters.Add("RecordingID", DbType.Int32, e.Keys["RecordingID"].ToString());
        this.sqldataRecordings.UpdateParameters.Add("RecordingName",  e.NewValues["Name"].ToString());`

Comment: I figured it out. First of all I was calling the update twice so I removed all of the update code from the code-behind. Secondly I'm attempting to only update one field but there are 3 fields in the gridview and I'm using Bind on each of the fields. Bind works as a two way parameter where it is both read in on select and used as a parameter upon update. That is the reason I was getting the to many parameters error. Once I changed Bind to Eval on the fields I'm not updating it worked fine. Thank you for the help

Comment: @TimBrooks Glad you figured it out.  I will update my answer to include the Bind/Eval thing (so if anyone else has the issue they know what you did to solve it).